# How to enforce certain UIImageView with SFSymbol to be in light mode even though the entire app is in dark mode?

Tags: ios, swift, sf-symbols

The following is the `UIImageView`, using SFSymbol `face.smiling`

- `UIImageView` background is pink color
- `UIImageView` tint is black color

[image]

When I switch my app to dark mode, the smiling face which use to be transparent color, has became solid black color.

The face line (eye, mouth, face border) used to be solid black color, had became transparent color.

[image]

I would like to avoid such outcome. Is there a way, to force `UIImageView` load SFSymbol in light mode, even though the entire app is using dark mode?

Here's the the testing looks like - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rhf9nn5vdK4 (This happens same when I test using real device and simulator)

Thanks.

Comment: That's weird, so the symbol switched to `face.smiling.fill` automatically?

Comment: Quick test, and I don't see the same behavior ... [mre]?

Comment: Strange. I can reproduce without issue - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rhf9nn5vdK4 Maybe I am targeting iOS 15?

Comment: Are you using Xcode 13 or 14 ?

Comment: I am using XCode 14. Just updated it few days ago.

Comment: hmmm... I don't have 14 installed anywhere yet. Do you get the same results if you use code instead of Storyboard?

Comment: @DogMag, Yes, same behavior even I use `imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "face.smiling")!`

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found out that in SwiftUI, you can just do the following to force the image to use the light mode variant:

```
Image(systemName: "face.smiling")
    .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
```

All thanks go to the answer in this forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/715500

Not sure about UIKit sadly.

Comment: For UIKit you can set the `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` property. `someImageView.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light`

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, but managed to easily fix it with the following:

```
iconImage: .init(systemName: colorScheme == .light ? "face.smiling" : "face.smiling.fill"),
```